# Interactive Python Network/Graph Modeling

Tags: python, graph, jung, piccolo

I'm looking for a python library that will allow me to interactively draw networks and graphs and attach data to nodes and edges.

I have found two libraries for Java that seem to do what I need: [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/) and [piccolo2d](http://www.piccolo2d.org/). Are there any python equivalents to these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU/Radio Companion, I was able to accomplish what I needed by performing some extensions here and there.

It is not the best solution since it introduces some ugly dependencies, but it works for now.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at:

- [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) - Here are [some graphs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) made with it.
- [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/index.html)
- [igraph](http://igraph.wikidot.com/)

Comment: Yes, I have looked at that, but there seems to no simple way of using it to model a graph.

Comment: @wkz I add two other libs, check that.